# why mongorestore command don't run?

Tags: mongodb

### I insert in the command prompt##

```
mongorestore --db gescom C:\Users\LENOVO\OneDrive\Bureau\S2\BD noSQL\TP\employes\employes.bson
```

### this is the problem log

2021-03-09T23:02:10.672+0100    error parsing command line options: error parsing positional arguments: provide only one polling interval in seconds and only one MongoDB connection string. Connection strings must begin with mongodb:// or mongodb+srv:// schemes
2021-03-09T23:02:10.718+0100    try 'mongorestore --help' for more information

Comment: That file path contains a space, so you need to quote it or escape the space.

Comment: Thank you a lot I feel so stupid haha

Comment: @Joe can you please post working connection string?

Comment: That seems like it should be a separate question.

Comment: Came here from Google, indeed the space was the problem - there are more of us :D.